# MySql Query to fetch the rows for column having one of the value from subquery

Tags: mysql

I want to query on MySQL server, Query should give the rows if one of the values in subquery contains in the column string.

I have many tables here.

Ex:

```
Employee
| id | name |...| data_as_string |
```

here `data_as_string` may contain department name in JSON format.

I have subquery, which  will return one or more department name, based on conditionals.
Based on the result returned by subquery, if `employee` table's `data_as_string` contains any of the department names in it. It should list. I tried `find_in_set` method but query gives an error telling subquery returned more than 1 row.

My Query was,

```
select * 
from employee 
where find_in_set((select name 
                   from `department` 
                   where 1=1), `data_as_string`) > 0
```

here actual condition is not 1=1. Query is just to understand the context to you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the following solution to my problem:

```
select * 
from employee e 
where data_as_string REGEXP CONCAT("'",(select REPLACE(GROUP_CONCAT(name),',','|') 
                                        from department 
                                        where 1=1)),"'")
```

This worked for me..